# Merging selective lines of code using Git?

Tags: git, merge, lines-of-code

I would like to force git to *always* merge using a (kind of) 3-way conflicts resolution. Moreover, I want to do it to the point of being able to choose single lines.

At the moment I am merging two branches. However, if possible, I'd like to know how to perform this task even when merging multiple branches.

Answer (score 2):

Git tries to do 3-way merging by default (the `recursive` strategy for 2 heads, and the `octopus` strategy for 3+ heads).

If you want to *see* 3-way resolution options when manually merging, try setting the `merge.conflictstyle` config option to `diff3`.

(See the Configuration section of the [`git-merge` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) for details on that option.)

Answer (score 0):

The blog post "[Five advanced Git merge techniques](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/01/advanced-git-merge/)" does give even more details on the diff3 setting:

> Turn diff3 conflicts using **`git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3`**.
>   The diff3 conflict style adds an extra section between the new `|||||||` marker and `=======` markers, which indicates:
>
> - the original contents of the section,
> - with your changes above and
> - their (the branch that is being merged in's) changes below.

Even without a diff tool, the command [`git show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) can help:

> When you are inside a merge, you can use a special `:N:` syntax, where `N` is a number, to automatically select one of the merge parents.

- `1` selects the common base commit (the lower revision),
- `2` selects your version ("`mine`"), and
- `3` selects their version (the higher revision).

> So `git show :3:foobar.txt` shows the upstream version of `foobar.txt`.